# How to create the following figure in TikZ (smooth closed curves)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to plot the following figure:

[image]

The quadrifolium shape in the middle is not hard to plot using polar coordiantes, e.g.,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[domain=0:360, scale=1,samples=500] plot (\x: {1.5*sin(2*\x)});
\draw[domain=180:270, scale=1,samples=500] plot (\x: {sin(2*\x)});

\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I'm having trouble with the other loops. I've tried to use

```
\draw plot[smooth cycle]
```

and manually plugging in suitable coordinates, I cannot obtain a smooth shaped curve. Any suggestions?

PS: The end result need not be identical to the drawing shown in the picture. However, the two small shapes and the two larger shapes are supposed to be mutually symmetric.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Hobby](https://ctan.org/pkg/hobby)?

Answer (score 5):

This could be a starting point :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90,fill opacity=.1,scale=3]
    \draw[red]
      (0,0) to[relative,in=190,out=0] (0,1)
      (0,0) to[relative,in=170,out=0] (-1,0);
    \draw[red,scale=.5] (0,0) .. controls +(-.5,0) and +(-.1,-.1) .. (-.5,.5) .. controls +(.1,.1) and +(0,.5) .. (0,0);

    \foreach~in{0,90,180,270}
      \filldraw[rotate=~] (0,0) .. controls +(-.5,0) and +(-.1,-.1) .. (-.5,.5) .. controls +(.1,.1) and +(0,.5) .. (0,0);

    \foreach~in{1,-1}
      \filldraw[yscale=~,rotate=45-~*45]
        (0,0) .. controls +(0,.55) and +(-.1,-.1) .. (-.3,.7) .. controls +(.1,.1) and +(0,.55) .. (0,0)
        (0,0) .. controls +(0,.8) and +(-.4,.1) .. (0,1) .. controls +(.3,-.1) and +(0,.7) .. (0,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]